# AWS TOOLKIT - How do I pretty print the response in the output panel of the VS Code AWS Toolkit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, aws-sam

In the `OUTPUT` panel of VS Code with the category being `AWS Toolkit` , the error codes I get when using AWS SAM to locally debug my applications are returned in unformatted JSON. As it currently stands, I have to copy that code and use a JSON formatter to read what it says.

Is there a way to pretty print or have it be displayed in a formatted way WITHIN the `OUTPUT` panel?

Answer (score 0):

Either

- start pretty printing your strings `log = (foo) => { console.log(JSON.stringify(foo, null, 2)) }`
- dont bother and start using vscode debug features like watches, more info here : https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/editor/debugging/#data-inspection